# Rails get version error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just stuck to searching my error when try to get my Rails version, anyone can help to solve this:

```
C:\Ruby24\bin>ruby -v ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053)
[i386-mingw32]

C:\Ruby24\bin>gem -v
2.6.12

C:\Ruby24\bin>rails -v
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require':
C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)   end
     ^
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/i18n.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
from C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.3/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby24/bin/rails:23:in `load'
from C:/Ruby24/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I ran Windows 7.

Comment: Have you install rails? gem install rails

Comment: Please post other code here.

Answer (score 0):

May be the gem `rails` not installed properly. Installing rails will solve the issue. It worked for me.

```
gem install rails
```